# Applying force on box2d body not working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am trying to move a body by applying force on it. But instead of moving in horizontal direction and making a trajectory, it is just falling down like i have not applied force on it. Here is the code:

```
public class Box2dTest implements ApplicationListener
{
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    World box2Dworld;
    Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private Body box2dBody;
    Sprite ball_sprite;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false);

        box2Dworld = new com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World(new Vector2(0.0F, -10.0F), true);
        new BoundryWall(this.box2Dworld, new PointF(0.0F, 0.0F), 800.0F, camera);

        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        createDynamicBody(110f, 150f);

        box2dBody.applyForce(new Vector2(30 * 1000, 0), box2dBody.getWorldCenter(), true);

        Texture ball_in_hand_Texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("test/ball_in_hand.png"));
        ball_in_hand_Texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        ball_sprite = new Sprite(ball_in_hand_Texture);
        ball_sprite.setPosition(110f, 150f);

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        box2Dworld.step(1.0f/60.0f, 6, 2);
        //box2Dworld.clearForces();

        camera.update();

        debugRenderer.render(box2Dworld, camera.combined);

        spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.draw(ball_sprite, 30 * box2dBody.getPosition().x, 30 * box2dBody.getPosition().y);

        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    private void createDynamicBody(float x, float y)
    {
        // First we create a body definition
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        // We set our body to dynamic, for something like ground which doesn't move we would set it to StaticBody
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.bullet = true;
        // Set our body's starting position in the world
//      bodyDef.position.set(x / 60.0f, y / 60.0f);

        //bodyDef.position.set(x / 30.0f, y / 30.0f);

        bodyDef.position.set(x, y);

        // Create our body in the world using our body definition
        box2dBody = this.box2Dworld.createBody(bodyDef);

        // Create a circle shape and set its radius to 6
        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(10f);

        // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = circle;
        fixtureDef.density = 0.5f; 
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f; // Make it bounce a little bit

        // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
        Fixture fixture = box2dBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        // Remember to dispose of any shapes after you're done with them!
        // BodyDef and FixtureDef don't need disposing, but shapes do.
        circle.dispose();
    }
}
```

Please help me. I am trying to solve this problem from last 3 days but of no avail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Force is usually applied continuously over many time steps, not just once like in your code. Maybe you could try ApplyLinearImpulse or SetLinearVelocity instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have created the world of very big size in which applying force of that value will have no effect. In fact applying force of any value will have no effect since the box2d world is limited to lower value.

I have not worked on Box2d for a very long time but i did faced the same issue. Try a small world around 12x20 and render your sprites accordingly. Then try applying the force, it will definately work.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create a world of small size please?

Comment: Here you are creating circle shaped body of radius 10 ... reduce it to .2f and render your sprite accordingly. Pixel to meter stuff is the line you should search... Please also see this. might help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208797/box2d-libgdx-a-bit-confused-about-the-pixels-to-meters-stuff